# Basic routing in Laravel gives me a 404 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to do basic routing using Laravel. But when I click on the link, the page displays a 404 error even though it was working earlier. I've made a folder that contains all the Blade files.

**Blade**

```
<a href="agenda/lack-of-water" class="text-decoration-none text-dark">
    Lack of Water
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function water()
{
    // ...
    return view('agenda.lack-of-water');
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('agenda/lack-of-water', 'App\Http\Controller\AgendazController@water')
    ->name('agenda/lack-of-water');
```

Comment: Do you have other routes which might conflict? Try putting this route at the top of your file to make sure nothing else conflicts.

Comment: BTW you have a typo - `App\Http\Controller` should probably be  `App\Http\Controllers` (though this would not give you a 404).

Comment: I think i removed the 's' when I was editing. Because it's there on my web.php file

Comment: you should avoid using relative paths for URLs

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to use a different controller as I was using AgendazController instead of AgendaController

Comment: In that case I suggest you close this question as a typo, it is not likely to help future users.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo